# Nuxt fetch() called repeatedly, multiple times

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am creating a base component that receives in image from an `Array.Buffer`, asynchronously.

Following [Nuxt documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch/), I thought `fetch()` would be the right call but when it's implemented it is called +20 times.

Why does this happen? I wanted to take advantage of `async/await` but looks like for now created() promises will have to do?

```
<template>
  <div class="image-container">
        <!-- <img :class="imgClasses" :src="`data:image/png;base64, ${image}`" alt="Preview Image" /> -->
  </div>
</template>


<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component, Prop } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'

@Component
export default class BasePreviewImage extends Vue {
  @Prop({ type: String }) id: string
  @Prop({ type: String, default: 'small' }) size: string

  image: string = ''

  get imgClasses() {
    return {
      [`preview-image-${this.size}`]: true
    }
  }

  async fetch() {
    console.log('fetching')
  }

  mounted() {
    console.log('mounted')
  }

  created() {
    console.log('Created BasePreviewImage')
  }
}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

fetch is called on server-side when rendering the route, and on client-side when navigating. so there is a chance to call/revoke the `fetch()` multiple times. and may be you have used this component at multiple places too. but the important things `fetch()` is deprecated where Nuxt >= 2.12

but you can control this way `fetchOnServer: false` then it will call on client side only.

```
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      posts: []
    }
  },
  async fetch () {
    this.posts = await this.$http.$get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  },
  fetchOnServer: false
}
</script>
```

Comment: Appreciate the input. I’ll try the setting when I’m back at my computer but I’m not sure that is the case. The element is only on the page once so it being called 23 times is...weird. Regardless, looks like with it be deprecated I’ll have to find a different way anyway.

Comment: Tested and looks like issue is unrelated to `fetchOnServer` setting. Updated question and re-posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62742764/nuxt-async-fetch-creating-multiple-instances-repeated-fetch-calls)