# Nuxt async fetch() creating multiple instances? Repeated fetch() calls

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-class-components

I have a simple `BasePreviewImage` component that needs to fetch an Array.Buffer() asynchronously from an internal API. However, it appears that `async fetch()` is called for every instance ever created despite the components themselves being destroyed.

Example:

```
<template>
  <div class="image-container">
  </div>
</template>


<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component, Prop } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'

@Component({})
export default class BasePreviewImage extends Vue {
  @Prop({ type: String }) id: string
  @Prop({ type: String, default: 'small' }) size: string

  image: string = ''

  async fetch() {
    console.log('async fetch', this)
  }

  created() {
    console.log('created')
  }

  mounted() {
    console.log('mounted')
  }

  beforeDestroy() {
    console.log('beforeDestroy')
  }
}
</script>
```

Output when I load a page with 1 `BasePreviewImage` component then back, then re-open the page. This continues calling fetch n times the page has been opened.

[image]

How do I avoid making the API call multiple times as a user navigates pages and is there some other memory leak going on here?

I'm not really sure if the problem is code, config, `vue`, `nuxt`, `nuxt-property-decorator`, `vue-class-component`, or somewhere else.

Related but not helpful: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/418